# compressing TIdMemoryBufferStream with TIdCompressorZLib

Tags: indy, indy10

i am asking about the possibility of compressing `TIdMemoryBufferStream` Using `TIdCompressorZLib` how can it be done properly using the following code

```
procedure TClientThread.SendBuffer(Buffer: TIdBytes; BufferSize: Cardinal);
Var
Strm: TIdMemoryBufferStream;
IdCompressorZLib : TIdCompressorZLib;
begin

Strm := TIdMemoryBufferStream.Create(PByte(Buffer), BufferSize);
IdCompressorZLib := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(nil);
try
// then can't figure what the right process to do 
FTCP.Socket.WriteLn('Stream');
FTCP.Socket.LargeStream := True;
FTCP.Socket.Write(Strm, 0, True);
finally
FreeAndNil(Strm);
FreeAndNil(IdCompressorZLib);
end;

end;
```

i am not sure about the right process that needs to be done

as example should i create another variable as `StrmB` then calling the compress to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TIdCompressorZLib` component is intended to be used only with the `Compressor` property of the `TIdHTTP` and `TIdFTP` components.

For general purpose compression over a TCP connection, you can assign a `TIdCompressionIntercept` component to the TCP connection's `IOHandler.Intercept` property, eg:

```
var
  Compressor : TIdCompressionIntercept;
begin
  Compressor := TIdCompressionIntercept.Create(nil);
  try
    Compressor.CompressionLevel := 9;
    FTCP.Socket.Intercept := Compressor;
    try
      // any data written here will be compressed....
    finally
      FTCP.Socket.Intercept := nil;
    end;
  finally
    Compressor.Free;
  end;
end;
```

However, since you are sending the byte size of the compressed data (by setting the `AWriteByteCount` parameter to True in `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)`), that will not work with the compression intercept.

Indy's `IdZLib` unit has a `TCompressionStream` class, and various `...CompressStream/Ex()` functions, that you can use instead, eg:

```
procedure TClientThread.SendBuffer(Buffer: TIdBytes; BufferSize: Cardinal);
var
  Strm: TMemoryStream;
  Compressor : TCompressionStream;
begin
  Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Compressor := TCompressionStream.Create(clMax, Strm, False);
    try
      WriteTIdBytesToStream(Compressor, Buffer, BufferSize);
    finally
      Compressor.Free;
    end;

    FTCP.Socket.WriteLn('Stream');
    FTCP.Socket.LargeStream := True;
    FTCP.Socket.Write(Strm, 0, True);
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure TClientThread.SendBuffer(Buffer: TIdBytes; BufferSize: Cardinal);
var
  InStrm: TIdMemoryBufferStream;
  OutStrm: TMemoryStream;
begin
  OutStrm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    InStrm := TIdMemoryBufferStream.Create(PByte(Buffer), BufferSize);
    try
      CompressStreamEx(InStrm, OutStrm, clMax, zsZLib);
    finally
      InStrm.Free;
    end;

    FTCP.Socket.WriteLn('Stream');
    FTCP.Socket.LargeStream := True;
    FTCP.Socket.Write(OutStrm, 0, True);
  finally
    OutStrm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: is there a decompress function when memory stream received inside idzlib ?

Comment: Did you look at the `IdZLib` unit yet?  It has `TDecompressionStream` and `...Decompress...()` functions